# What would happen to a car with a center of gravity below the center of roll while steering?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In reference to this question: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/44296/

I have a few questions about this:

- What would happen to the steering of a car if you did accomplish lowering the center of gravity to be below the center of roll?
- Would the car roll to the inside or outside of the turn? -the answer seems to be inside based on the monorail example
- What would happen to the steering forces in relation to the steering and suspension components compared to usual?
- Would there be any risks associated with a setup like this, like there is for an extremely high CoG?

Edit: to clarify, I'm imagining something like a supercar, the center of gravity below the center of roll but above the steering surface, extremely low to the ground

Comment: Example system: hanging rollercoaster s. Though they have less sophisticated suspension than a modern automobile.

Comment: you mean such a car: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Funivia_Rote_Nase_alt.JPG/265px-Funivia_Rote_Nase_alt.JPG

Comment: hehe, the same thought at the same time :)

Comment: While it's a good real life example, I have something different in mind, I'll edit c: